# SqlCommand.ExecuteReader returns no rows using Stored Proc with output parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that accepts an input and returns multiple columns.  The stored procedure works when I execute it from SSMS and also inside of VS 2013.  However when I try and execute it using SqlCommand.ExecuteReader the reader doesn't have any rows in it.  If I remove the output parameters from the proc and from the SqlCommand, while still keeping the one input parameter, I am able to return the row that I am looking for.

Here is the stored proc

```
create Proc sp_ReturnSingleGame
    @GameName varchar(100) output,
    @PlatformName varchar(50) output,
    @ConditionShortDescription varchar(30) output,
    @RetailCost decimal(6,2) output,
    @InStock bit output,
    @GameID int
AS
    select @GameName = GameName, @PlatformName = PlatformName, 
           @ConditionShortDescription = ConditionShortDescription, @RetailCost = RetailCost
         from   Games inner join Condition 
         on     Games.ConditionID = Condition.ConditionID 
                inner join ConsolePlatform
         on Games.PlatformID = ConsolePlatform.PlatformID
         Where Games.GameID = @GameID

    if exists (select GameID 
               From SaleItemized
               Where GameID = @GameID)
        Begin
            set @InStock = 1;
        end
    else
        Begin
            set @InStock = 0;
        end
```

Here is my C# code

```
public Game ReturnSingleGame(int gameId)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=mylaptop; integrated security=true; database=GameStoreDB;");

    SqlCommand command = this.ReturnCommandForSp_ReturnSingleGame(connection, gameId);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows == true)
        {
            reader.Read();
            game.GameId = gameId;
            game.GameName = reader["GameName"].ToString();
            game.PlatformName = reader["PlatformName"].ToString();
            game.RetailCost = (decimal) reader["RetailCost"];
        }
        else
        {
            var exception = new ApplicationException("Game was not found");
            throw exception;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
    return game;
}

private SqlCommand CommandForSp_ReturnSingleGame(SqlConnection connection, int gameId)
{
    string storedProc = @"dbo.sp_ReturnSingleGame";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(storedProc, connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.Add("@GameName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "GameName");
    command.Parameters["@GameName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    command.Parameters.Add("@PlatformName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "PlatformName");
    command.Parameters["@PlatformName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    command.Parameters.Add("@ConditionShortDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, "ConditionShortDescription");
    command.Parameters["@ConditionShortDescription"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    command.Parameters.Add("@RetailCost", SqlDbType.Decimal);
    command.Parameters["@RetailCost"].SourceColumn = "RetailCost";
    command.Parameters["@RetailCost"].Precision = 6;
    command.Parameters["@RetailCost"].Scale = 2;
    command.Parameters["@RetailCost"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    command.Parameters.Add("@InStock", SqlDbType.Bit);
    command.Parameters["@InStock"].SourceColumn = "InStock";
    command.Parameters["@InStock"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    command.Parameters.Add("@GameID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = gameId;
    command.Parameters["@GameID"].SourceColumn = "GameID";
    command.Parameters["@GameID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    command.Prepare();

    return command;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stored procedure provided by you actually doesn't return any rows of data.

All it does - is just set output parameters.

So you don't need any `SqlDataReader` to retrieve there parameters.

Just call `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` and then get your parameters values from `command.Parameters["@GameName"].Value` and so on.

Comment: Did not know that.  Obviously a beginner here.  I will try that. Thanks

Comment: I had some incorrect understanding of my stored proc.  In my particular example it will not return a dataset so iterating through a collection or rows doesn't add up and that code should be pitched and it is like you said I should retrieve the values from the parameter.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Andy.

For you snippet from one of my project is:`

```
 DbCommand Cmd = null;
  using (DataClient client = new DataClient())
  {
 SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[2];
 parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
 parameters[0].Size = 10;
 parameters[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
 parameters[1] = new SqlParameter("@YourParameterName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
 parameters[1].Value = Class.PropertyName;
 parameters[2] = new SqlParameter("@Year", SqlDbType.Int);
 client.ExecuteNonQuery("ReturnCommandForSp_ReturnSingleGame", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters, ref Cmd);

 Then retrieve it like this
 int yourReturnValue= Convert.ToInt32(Cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value);
 }
```

Hope it helps.