# SqlDataReader.Read() error, reading values from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to ASP.NET, and I am having issues with my API-controller function. I am calling a stored procedure and mapping the results to a model, then aggregating it into a list of Strings, but at the end of the code it returns an empty string. I noticed that execution skips the while block, and I'm not sure why, because when I set break points there it doesn't hit.

this is the output of the stored procedure when i run in in sqlserver

[image]

This is my code:

**The UserModel**

```
   using System;
   using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

   namespace Fnk.Models{
      public class UserModel{
        [Required]
        public string id {get; set;}
        [Required]
        public string Username{get; set;} 
        [Required]
        public string Email {get; set;} 
        [Required]
        public string UserRole {get; set;}
      }
   }
```

**The Api-controller** - receives an email

```
        public IActionResult getusers([FromRoute] string email){

            string conn = Configuration.GetConnectionString("FintrakDBConnection");         
            var columns = new List<string>();  // List<string> pTypes;

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(conn)) {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("scb_getUserRoles", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter {
                    ParameterName = "email",
                    Value = email,
                });

               con.Open();

               using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){   ///code works up to this point

                   while(reader.Read()){   // breakpoint here shows the 4 columns... 

                        var obj = new UserModel(); 

                        if (reader["id"] != DBNull.Value) 
                            obj.id = reader["id"].ToString(); 

                        if (reader["UserName"] != DBNull.Value)
                            obj.Username = reader["UserName"].ToString(); 

                        if (reader["Email"] != DBNull.Value)
                            obj.Email = reader["Email"].ToString(); 

                        if (reader["RoleId"] != DBNull.Value) 
                            obj.UserRole = reader["RoleId"].ToString();

                        columns.Add(obj.id);  
                        columns.Add(obj.Username);      
                        columns.Add(obj.UserRole);  
                        columns.Add(obj.Email);     
                    }
                    reader.Close();
               }                  
                con.Close();
            }
            return Ok(columns.ToArray());  //returns an empty array.. dont know why
          }
```

At this point `while(reader.Read())` the system shows that it has read the database and updated the reader, but execution skips the while loop and returns an empty array.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does the sproc `scb_getUserRoles` looks like? Does it has output parameters or outputs a result set?

Comment: I don't know what the output of your SP looks like. Check this out maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178032/sqlcommand-executereader-returns-no-rows-using-stored-proc-with-output-parameter

Comment: i just updated the question, to show what the stored procedure looks like.

Comment: try to put @ in this line ParameterName = "@email",

Comment: @OrlandoAguilera it works without the @ symbol,  the query executes and gets to the while block, but if you insist, let me try so.

Comment: Was the problem resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested as per my table data which works fine.

```
    string connectionString = @"data source=MS-KIRON-01;initial catalog=MSTestDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
    var columns = new List<string>();  // List<string> pTypes;

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Username, Email FROM TestTable", con);

        con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {   ///code works up to this point
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {   // breakpoint here shows the 4 columns... 

                    var obj = new UserModel();

                    if (reader["Username"] != DBNull.Value)
                        obj.Username = reader["Username"].ToString();

                    if (reader["Email"] != DBNull.Value)
                        obj.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
                    columns.Add(obj.Username);
                    columns.Add(obj.Email);
                }

            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    return columns.ToArray();
```

> Everything seems alright I don't know why you are getting null array.
>   One Modification I would suggest [`if (reader.HasRows) {}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader) when your
>   reader doesn't have any record it would through exception to handle
>   this you could use it as I have already attached on my example.

Comment: sincerely... i've checked everything, let me try your approach and see..

Comment: Sure you can, let me know if anymore problem encountered, No worry. Good luck.

Comment: please i need help, on this same issue.. do you have team viewer maybe you could help me resolve this issue remotely, because i'm back to it.

Comment: no it didnt work, i moved on to solve other issues that was why.. but i'm back here, since its the same application, i tried to work on other modules, but now i want to handle the user module.. and i'm back to this.

Comment: you told me to use reader.HasRows - that returns false on my code, and the block of code refuses to execute, not sure why.

Comment: If there is no data from response then inside code block would not executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208486/discussion-between-ande-caleb-and-md-farid-uddin-kiron).

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer @AndeCaleb because `while (reader.Read())` wont throw an exception if it has no rows. So adding the `if (reader.HasRows) {}` condition has no added benefits, unless you were to log out no records or something like that. But either way that doesn't make this a solution. Please revisit and mark correct answers only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not accidentally executing the `reader.Read()` in a watch window or Immediate window, as if there is only one record, the  next Read() will be false...?

Note you have properly used `using` so you do not need to close your `reader` or `con`